# Weird setState behaviour with MaterialUI in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, setstate

I'm trying to show an input component from material-ui, but when I write some text (something like 3 letters), the page crashes.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';

export default function ComposedTextField() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = event => {
    setState((state) => event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Input id="component-simple" value={state} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}
```

I've noticed that replacing `setState((state) => event.target.value);` with `setState(event.target.value);` fixes the issue, but I need (in my real project) to use the full version of setState.

Does anybody understand why the `setState((state) => event.target.value);` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `event` object is re-used after the callback has run, so it [cannot be used asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) like what the code does right now.

Grab whatever values you need out of the event into their own variables:

```
const handleChange = event => {
  const { value } = event.target
  setState((state) => value);
};
```

Alternatively if you need access to the whole event, you can use `event.persist()` to remove the object from the pool and not have it re-used.